# Dynamically render components from a Immutable.js map

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js

For managing my immutable redux state, I need to read an Immutable state and render components based on it.

See this code from [webpackbin](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KjcwS8bqBWw4Z8UD8ED/)

My actual code is quite long, but summarizing it could be something like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'
import {fromJS} from 'immutable'
import Filters from './Filters'


const data = fromJS({
  Filter1: ['english', 'french', 'spanish'],
  Filter2: ['small', 'big']
})

render(<Filters filterMap={data} />, document.querySelector('#app'))
```

I need to render all the filters, so I read filterMap parameter and try to dynamically render elements as I read it:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import {fromJS, map} from 'immutable'
import Filter1 from './Filter1'
import Filter2 from './Filter2'

const filters = { Filter1, Filter2 }

const Filter = ({ filterMap }) => (
  <div>
    { filterMap.entrySeq().forEach((item) => {
      const FilterElement = filters[item[0]]
      console.log('item0: ' + item[0])
      console.log('item1:' + item[1])
      console.log (FilterElement)
      return <FilterElement />
    })
    }
  </div>
)

export default Filter
```

However I only get a number '2'. No component get rendered :-(

I should get something like (return values from Filter1 and Filter2 components):

```
<h1>This is filter1</h1>
<h1>This is filter2</h1>
```

Filter1 and Filter2 code:

```
import React from 'react'

function Filter2 () {
  return (
    <h1>This is filter2</h1> 
  )
}

export default Filter2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `map` function instead of `forEach`:

```
{ filterMap.entrySeq().forEach((item) => {
// change to:
{ filterMap.entrySeq().map((item) => {
```

Map is used to create a new list from the previous list turning each element into the element returned by the provided function. `forEach` on the other hand has no return value and therefore nothing is rendered.